# iphone popviewcontroll problem

Tags: iphone, ios4

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

    //Some code to go to the next page
    NSString *selectedCountry = [arraycountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *selectedCountry1 = [arycountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    profilepage *detailViewController = [[profilepage alloc] initWithNibName:@"profilepage" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
    detailViewController.selectedCountry1 = selectedCountry1;
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];
```

This is my code,how can i pass selectedCountry and SelectedCountry1 to profilepage,,,

i try but,i didnt get any values, please help me,thnkzzz

Comment: How did u get the detailViewController instace in the next class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `detailViewController` is the next view, you should be using `pushViewControllerAnimated:animated:` instead of `popViewControllerAnimated:`. Logically, push goes forward and pop goes backward.

The navigation stack is described in the [Navigation Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1) section of the View Controller Programming Guide.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:detailViewController
                           animated:YES];

[detailViewController release];
```

Comment: but, i got a warning message shows that,uinavigationcontroll may not responce to popviewcontroller,,sir i just want to pass selecetdcountries and selectedcountry1 to previous page by popcontroller method,,,